# Why is $T^4+6T^2-8T-3\in\mathbb Q[T]$ is irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> Why is $T^4+6T^2-8T-3\in\mathbb Q[T]$ is irreducible ?

Obviously Eisenstein doesn't work, but can we do a substitution and obtain a form such that the criterion is applicable ?

We didn't cover it in the lecture, but I've seen now there's a so called rational root theorem, If I didn't understand it wrong, does it state:

For any polynomials with integer coefficients and having a rational solution, say $x=p/q$ must $p$ be a factor of $a_0$(here $-3$) and $q$ a factor of leading coefficient, (here $1$), so in this case there is no rational root $\implies$ we cannot factor it as $(T^3+...)(T+...)$, it must be of the form $(T^2+aT+b)(T^2+cT+d)$ am I wrong ?

> EDIT: After the hint of ajotatxe. I got the following relations;

$\begin{cases}bd=-3\\ad+bc=-8\\ac+b+d=6\\a+c=0\end{cases}$

Substituting $c=-a$ and $d=\frac{-3}b$ in the second equation and multiplying it by $b$, I have:

$ab^2-8b+3b=0$, I assume that $a$ is rational and consider $b$ as an indeterminate, thus;

$\displaystyle b_{1,2}=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{16-3a^2}}{a}$

In both cases $b$ is irrational, contradiction.

Can somebody confirm it ?

Comment: You are on the right way . You might want to look here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308984/show-x6-1-5x5-3x-4-5-is-irreducible-in-mathbb-qx?rq=1 for similar question.

Comment: What's going on if $a=2$? Then I can't see anything irrational.

Comment: @user26857 If it's the only possibility then I continue; $b$ is either $0$ (impossible, $bd=-3$) or $b=4$ (impossible 3rd relation is wrong then)

Comment: This was only a poor example. But $a\in\mathbb Q$, and then write it as $m/n$ and see when $16n^2-3m^2$ is a perfect square. I'd say that there is some work left to do. (Anyway, I'd never follow this way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of problems you can suppose $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$; see [Gauss' Lemma](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~robbin/541dir/gaussLemma.pdf). Then the system of equations becomes more tractable since from $bd=-3$ you get only few cases for $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right path. Expand the product $(T^2+aT+b)(T^2+cT+d)$ and equal coefficients.